# In .NET is there a tool that creates business objects and database tables from forms?

Tags: .net, rad

Let's say you've designed a form in Visual Studio, with a whole series of texboxes, maybe a data-grid and you've named all the controls and specified what data-types are allowed in each.

Is there a tool that will then create all the business objects, database tables and all the code to make that work?

I would have thought there should be a tool do that, because once you have created a form, you essentially have enough information for a database table and all the code-layers in between. (You may have to specify which of the controls represents the primary key and any foreign keys.)

Comment: Don't be lazy! :) There is no any tool like you think. But I am pretty sure that you can create some Visual Studio plugin to automate this task.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: Aren't there RAD tools?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is extremely close to what you get with [Visual Studio Lightswitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch).

It's not exactl what yu're describing, but pretty close.  In VS Lightswitch, you create the forms and data *together* As you're creating the forms, you're creating the database and all of the logic necessary to interact with it. (or create forms to attach to existing data)

It's extremely good for quick and dirty apps, but in my experience, it is quite limiting.

The web counterpart is [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-dynamic-data/getting-started-with-dynamic-data).  That's a lot easier to extend, add to, and modify than are Lightswitch apps.  However, with Dynamic Data, it's the reverse of what you're suggesting.  You create the database properly and then hook it up with amazingly little effort.

Comment: I don't see how you could do it backwards. How could it work out how you want the form designed?

Comment: I think the UI should be the starting point, since that's where the design is.

Comment: I think you'd get a lot of debate on that one.  Modeling the data to reflect the business objects is usually my first task.  I used to take the "UI first" approach, but learned the hard way that if you go with how the customer wants it to look, it will almost certainly not function the way they need.  But that's off-topic for this site.  Maybe something to bring up at programmers.stackexchange.